# different shaped open basis on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

$J_1$ be the smallest topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ containing the sets $(a,b)\times (c,d)\forall a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$

$J_2$ be the smallest topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ containing the sets $\{(x,y):(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2<c,\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R},c>0\}$

$J_3$ be the smallest topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ containing the sets $\{(x,y):|(x-a)|+|(y-b)|<c,\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R},c>0\}$

My question is is true that $J_1=J_2=J_3$?or there is some containement relationship among them?

In exam hall I  thought that any open set of $J_1$,I can push it into some open set of $J_2,J_3$ and I can do the same thing for other two, so they are equal? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will all be the same. You need to show that you can fit each basis element of $J_1$ inside a basis element of $J_2$ inside a (... think matryoshka dolls). If you draw a picture of the sets, you'll see why it's true intuitively, and then you just need to back it up with a little algebra.